# Установить QByteArray в QDataStream

Tags: qt

В `QDataStream` есть метод `setIDevice(QIODevice *)`, но нету такого метода, чтобы установить `QByteArray`. Во всяком случае, я не нашел. Знаю, что можно создавая `QDataStream` объект через конструктор это сделать, но у меня уже объект есть, и нужно переустановить его на `QByteArray`. Есть ли какой то способ? И если на самом деле нет такого метода, то с чего это? Почему нет?

Comment: аа, ну вот отлично.) спасибо большое!!!
потому что у меня в той функции уже уже есть объект QDataStream out.
не хотелось создавать новый объект, а перенастроить тот, старый.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Не забудьте отметить ответ как правильный!)) Успехов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем Вам не подошли конструкторы:

```
QDataStream ( QByteArray * a, QIODevice::OpenMode mode )
QDataStream ( const QByteArray & a )
```

?

Хотя в принципе можно сделать так:

```
QByteArray bytes;
QBuffer buffer(&bytes);
QDataStream stream;
stream.setDevice(&buffer);
```